# Calculate Computed Variables before 'Tab' key is pressed- Knockout

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-3.0

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/divekarvinit/zdnmk9yr/17/) is fiddle which has two input fields. The fiddle contains on span tag which is a computed variable calculated by concatenating the two inputs.

**HTML**

```
<div style="width : 200px; height : 80px; border: 1px solid red" data-bind="click : clicked">
  <input type="text" data-bind="value : input1, event : { keydown : function(){ return tabOut(event)}}" />
  <input type="text" data-bind="value : input2" />
  <span data-bind="text : result"></span>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
function MyVM() {
  this.input1 = ko.observable('');
  this.input2 = ko.observable('');
  this.result = ko.computed(function() {
        console.log('Computed fired at ' + new Date());
    return this.input1() + ' ' + this.input2();

  }, this);

  this.clicked = function() {
  }

  this.tabOut = function() {
    if (event.keyCode == 9) {
        console.log('Tab fired at ' + new Date());
        this.clicked(event);
    };
    return true;
  }
}

var viewModel = new MyVM();
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

If you enter input in the field and press 'Tab' key (without clicking anywhere), first, `keydown` event is fired and then the computed variable is calculated.

I want the computed variable to be calculated before firing the event. How can I achieve the same?

I have looked at the `valueUpdate` binding in the [docs](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/value-binding.html). I can set the `valueUpdate : afterKeydown`to achieve the result but I want to keep the valueUpdate to its default value. Is there any other way to obtain desired result?

Answer (score 0):

Simple. Use `textInput` binding instead of `value` binding.

```
<div style="width : 200px; height : 80px; border: 1px solid red" data-bind="click : clicked">
   <input type="text" data-bind="textInput: input1, event : { keydown : function(){ return tabOut(event)}}" />
   <input type="text" data-bind="textInput: input2" />
   <span data-bind="text : result"></span>
</div>
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/zdnmk9yr/21/) is the updated fiddle.

Comment: This gives the same output as `valueupdate:afterkeydown`. I do not want the computed variables to be calculated on key down but after out of focus(default behavior).

Comment: You want the calculation to happen when it's out of focus but before the keydown event is triggered? How is that possible?